'onButtonClick(View)' is already defined and Constant expression required
Im trying to make a simple calculator in android studio and I get an error saying'onButtonClick(View)' is already defined in 'com.example.calculator.MainActivity' and Constant expression required
this is where the error is at
public void onButtonClick(View view)

    public void onButtonClick(View view){
        Button button =(Button) view;
        String buttonText = button.getText().toString();
    }
    private void calculateResult() {
        String displayContent = display.getText().toString();
        if (!displayContent.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                double displayedValue = Double.parseDouble(displayContent);
                switch (lastOperation) {
                    case "+":
                        currentValue += displayedValue;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        currentValue -= displayedValue;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        currentValue *= displayedValue;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        if (displayedValue != 0) {
                            currentValue /= displayedValue;
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot divide by zero",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "=":
                        currentValue = displayedValue;
                        break;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        updateDsiplay(currentValue);
    }
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    private void updateDsiplay(double value){
        DecimalFormat format= new DecimalFormat("0.############");
        display.setText(format.format(value));
    }
    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    public void onButtonClick(View view){
        if(clearDisplay){
            display.setText("");
            clearDisplay = false;
        }
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.button_equal:
                calculateResult();
                lastOperation="=";
                clearDisplay=true;
                break;
            case R.id.button_plus:
            case R.id.button_minus:
            case R.id.button_multiply:
            case R.id.button_divide:
                performOperation(((Button) view).getText().toString());
                break;
            case R.id.button_clear:
                display.setText("");
                currentValue = 0;
                lastOperation = "=";
                clearDisplay = false;
                break;
            default:
                if (clearDisplay){
                    display.setText("");
                    currentValue=0;
                    clearDisplay=false;
                }
                String buttonText = ((Button) view).getText().toString();
                display.append(buttonText);
                break;
        }
    }
    private void performOperation(String operation){
        if(!display.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            calculateResult();
        }
        lastOperation=operation;
        clearDisplay = true;
    }

}

tried combining the two onButtonClick but show up another problem

What is the problem with "combining" the two onButtonClick Methods? Looks like the first one is not really doing anything anyway, so you could just remove it.

You are declaring the function onButtonClick two times with the same argument types. This is not allowed in Java, each function signature has to be unique.
The two functions with signature
public void onButtonClick(View view){
    // ...
}

can be merged into a single function as follows:
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    Button button = (Button) view;
    String buttonText = button.getText().toString();

    if (clearDisplay) {
        display.setText("");
        clearDisplay = false;
    }

    int id = view.getId();
    if (id == R.id.button_equal) {
        calculateResult();
        lastOperation = "=";
        clearDisplay = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.button_plus 
            || id == R.id.button_minus 
            || id == R.id.button_multiply 
            || id == R.id.button_divide) {
        performOperation(buttonText);
    } else if (id == R.id.button_clear) {
        display.setText("");
        currentValue = 0;
        lastOperation = "=";
        clearDisplay = false;
    } else {
        if (clearDisplay) {
            display.setText("");
            currentValue = 0;
            clearDisplay = false;
        }
        display.append(buttonText);
    }
}

Make sure to only set this function as onClick to Buttons. We also need to use if-else instead of switch as explained here.  Note that I haven't verified the logic of your implementation.

Constant expression required this is what happen to all case R.id.button* when i do that

i edited my comment is seems i put 2 button text

See my edited answer. Use an if else instead of a switch.
